# Include a .tikz file into LaTeX considering the graphics path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to include a .tikz figure in my document, using:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\input{pic/fig1}
\caption{Figure 1.}
\end{figure}
```

My .tex file is in my file "LaTeX". The .tikz file is in a file "pic", which is in the "LaTeX" file. The above doesn't work. I get an error:

```
File `pic/input_output.tex' not found. \input{pic/input_output}
```

It's weird, because input_output is clearly in the "pic" file!

Comment: Is your file called `input_output.tex` or `input_output.tikz`? Note from the error that LaTeX looks for a file called `input_output.tex`, if the file ending is `.tikz` you need to state that explicitly e.g. `\input{filename.tikz}`.

Comment: I have just tried to open the input_output file. Interestingly, maybe disturbingly, in TeXstudio  file->open->LaTeX->pic  leads to an empty file. There is not a single picture in this file. It's weird. When I open the file from Desktop, everything is in there, however the file type is not specified and I can't open them. I have created the files on a different PC and then transferred them. On the other PC everything worked fine with TeXstudio.

Comment: Is your file called `input_output.tex` or `input_output.tikz`?

Comment: (Your use of the word "file" for what is usually called "folder" or "directory" is a bit confusing at first.) I'm guessing TeXstudio has some filter so it only shows files of a specific type, and `.tikz`, if that's what you've used, is not one of them. Can you  select "All files" or something?

Comment: right, sorry, it's folder of course! Anyways, I have just renamed the file into input_output.tex and now the error doesn't show up anymore. I still don't know if the problem is solved completely, since  other errors occur.  But I think I have to treat these separately

Comment: Well, the problem you have described appears to be solved (as I mentioned you could also have written `\input{pic/input_output.tikz}`, instead of renaming the file). If you get other errors, that's a different problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. On a Unix-ish system, the usage is accurate, though. Everything is a file. A directory is just a file. I agree, however, that describing things accurately leads to a certain loss of communicative comfort :).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `\input{file}`, LaTeX assumes that you want to input a `.tex` file, so it looks for a file called `file.tex`. Files with any other extensions are ignored. But you can specify the extension, e.g. with `\input{file.tikz}`, LaTeX will look for a file called `file.tikz` (and not `file.tikz.tex`).

Hence, you need to say

```
\input{pic/input_output.tikz}
```

and not

```
\input{pic/input_output}
```

(Or you can rename the file to `input_output.tex`.)

Note that the error message in this case is actually quite clear, if you pay attention to the extension that is given in the error, and compare that with the extension of your file.

Comment: Ah, merci beaucoup. Mange takk.